# NavigationBar weird extra white space

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview, uinavigationbar

I'm using a usual view controller with UITableView which is embedded into a navigation controller which is embedded into a tabbar controller:

- TabBar Controller
- Navigation Controller
- UIViewController with TableView

I'm using NavBar with a large title. When I scroll up in a usual way navigation bar with its large title has normal height. But when I touch status bar and tableView scrolls to top, navigation bar gets extra white space between a status bar and its title:

Normal space when scrolling with a finger: https://ibb.co/0BWgB0T

Extra space when touching status bar: https://ibb.co/LxFwDKx

The only thing that helps to avoid that extra space is the following:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: 0)
```

But it makes tabBar grey, not white as it should be and anyway seems like a quite incorrect solution.

Have anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: It's an expected behavior when you deal with `UITableView`. Table views scrolls to top when you tap on the status bar by default in iOS. Try that in the **Settings** app in your device, you will find similar behavior.

Comment: @nayem, yeah, I know :) The problem I described is that using tableView's scrollsToTop (touching status bar) increases navBar height. Anyway I've already found a solution and wrote it below

Comment: That is not the problem. Rather you're using large titled navigation bar which occupies the increased height. As the table view scrolls to top, it forces navigation bar to be reset to its default initial state, that's why you get that increased navigation bar height. As I've mentioned in the previous comment, try to check the behavior in the **Settings** app, you will know what I meant.

Comment: I'm facing EXACTLY the same issue! But unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me. Do you have any updates? (Btw, nayem doesn't know what it is talking about)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, suddenly I've found a solution. Yes, it includes this line of code:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: 0)
```

But also I had to set a tabBar color to preferable and disable its "Translucent" property in Interface Builder.

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Writing it here in case it helps someone.

The visual of my issue is the same as yours, but for me it was related to the refreshing component (for pull to refresh).

In case you have the pull to refresh enabled for you component, remember to call `endRefreshing()`, or you'll get that strange extra space.

Thank you a lot for you question and suggestion Ilya!

Have a great one.